# Regarding Formatting the Excel sheet using EPPlus in C#

Tags: c#, epplus

I have been working on Excel Sheet Formatting using EPPlus. I am able to create group when the Excel Sheet is in a ordered one .But if the input comes unordered and I have to group then I am facing issue.

The Excel input looks like in the problematic sceario:

Field1           Field2    Field3

1                 XYZ       ABC

3.1               PRQ       SDE

1.1               AB        ST

1.2               MN        RT

like wise and all 1 related row should be at one group like in ascending order.

I have written the below which if sorted works fine but not able to figure out if the input is jumbled up/ not sorted.

Here is my code.

Thanks for your help.

```
namespace EPPlusTestDemo {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set the File name and get the output directory

            var fileName = "Example-File-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--hh-mm-ss") + ".xlsx";
            var outputDir = @"C:\Users\asder\Desktop\outpath\" + fileName;

            // Create the file using the FileInfo object
            var file = new FileInfo(outputDir);

            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file))
            {
                // Adding a new worksheet to the empty workbook
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Example list - " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

                // --------- Data and styling goes here -------------- //

                // Header part

                worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Field1";
                worksheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "Field2";
                worksheet.Cells["C1"].Value = "Field3";
                worksheet.Cells["D1"].Value = "Field4";
                worksheet.Cells["E1"].Value = "Field5";

                worksheet.Cells["A1:E1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;

                // The row number 
                int initialRowNum = 2;
                int rowNumber = initialRowNum;

                #region input_toExcel

                // Filling the data from the 2nd row of the excel sheet

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "1";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "GRP";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";

                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "1.1";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "Item";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";


                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "1.2";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "Item";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";

                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "1.3";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "Item";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";


                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "1.4";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "Item";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";


                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "2";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "GRP";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";

                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "2.1";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "Item";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";

                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "2.2";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "Item";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";


                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "2.3";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "Item";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";


                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "2.4";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "Item";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";

                #endregion


                // Grouping after comparing the Cell Value 
                for ( var rowIndex = initialRowNum; worksheet.Row(rowIndex) != null; rowIndex++)
                {
                    // Checking for NULL in the Excel Sheet
                    var comapreable = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1].GetValue<string>();

                    // Group Counter 
                    int count = 0;

                    if (comapreable != null)
                    {
                        Regex regexIntegral = new Regex(@"\d");
                        Match matchIntegral = regexIntegral.Match(comapreable);

                        Regex regexDouble = new Regex(@"([1-9]+)\.([1-9]+)");
                        Match matchDouble = regexDouble.Match(comapreable);


                        // Checking if the Cell of the Excel sheet contains any integral value
                        if ( matchIntegral.Success == true )
                        {
                            count++; // Incrementing the Group Level Counter

                            // Checking if the Cell contains the decimal values

                            if ( matchDouble.Success == true )
                            {
                                worksheet.Row(rowIndex).OutlineLevel = count;
                                worksheet.Row(rowIndex).Collapsed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Saving the File
                package.Save();
            }
            // Console.ReadKey();
        }
    } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the below findings on my question.Please find the code below.
Please do comment if you feel there are more good solutions.  Thanks

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Set the File name and get the output directory

            var fileName = "Example-File-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--hh-mm-ss") + ".xlsx";
            var outputDir = @"E:\C#Programming\ExcelFormattingProject\outpath\" + fileName;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            // Create the file using the FileInfo object
            var file = new FileInfo(outputDir);

            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file))
            {
                // Adding a new worksheet to the empty workbook
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Example list - " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

                // --------- Data and styling goes here -------------- //

                // Header part

                worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Field1";
                worksheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "Field2";
                worksheet.Cells["C1"].Value = "Field3";
                worksheet.Cells["D1"].Value = "Field4";
                worksheet.Cells["E1"].Value = "Field5";

                worksheet.Cells["A1:E1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;

                // The row number 
                int initialRowNum = 2;
                int rowNumber = initialRowNum;

                #region input_toExcel

                // Filling the data from the 2nd row of the excel sheet

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "1";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "GRP";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";

                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "2.1";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "Item2.1";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";


                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "1.2";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "Item1.2";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";

                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "1.3";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "Item";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";


                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "1.4";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "Item";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";


                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "2";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "GRP";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";

                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "1.1";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "Item";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";

                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "2.2";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "Item";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";


                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "2.3";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "Item";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";


                rowNumber++;

                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = "2.4";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = "Item";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = "ABC";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = "CDE";
                worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value = "ABCD";



                #endregion

                //  Need to fetch the data as a row or recorset and then sort it and place it to a new Excel

                //worksheet.Cells["A2:A11"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#0\\.00";

                for (var rowIndex = 1;rowIndex < 11; rowIndex++)
                {
                    var colIndex = 1;

                    for (; colIndex <= 5;)
                    {
                        // Filling the First Row of the DataTable with the Field Name as on the Excel Sheet
                        if (rowIndex == 1)
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex].Text));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
                        }
                        colIndex++;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
                }

                // Inserting Values in the DataTable
                for (var rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < 11; rowIndex++)
                {
                        // Filling the DataTable with Excel Contents
                        for (var colIndex = 1; colIndex <= 5;)
                        {
                                dt.Rows[rowIndex - 1][colIndex - 1] = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex+1, colIndex].Text;
                                colIndex++;
                        }
                }

                // Sorting the DataTable 
                DataTable dtOut = null;
                dt.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "Field1", "Field2", "Field3", "Field4", "Field5");
                dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Field1";
                dtOut = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "Field1", "Field2","Field3","Field4","Field5");


                // Exporting the DataTable to the WorkSheet of the Excel
                worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dtOut, true);



                #endregion

                // Grouping after comparing the Cell Value 
                for ( var rowIndex = 2; worksheet.Row(rowIndex) != null; rowIndex++)
                  {
                    // Checking for NULL in the Excel Sheet
                    var comapreable = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1].GetValue<string>();

                    // Group Counter 
                    int count = 0;

                    if (comapreable != null)
                    {
                        Regex regexIntegral = new Regex(@"\d");
                        Match matchIntegral = regexIntegral.Match(comapreable);

                        Regex regexDouble = new Regex(@"([1-9]+)\.([1-9]+)");
                        Match matchDouble = regexDouble.Match(comapreable);


                        // Checking if the Cell of the Excel sheet contains any integral value
                        if ( matchIntegral.Success == true )
                        {
                            count++; // Incrementing the Group Level Counter

                            // Checking if the Cell contains the decimal values

                            if ( matchDouble.Success == true )
                            {
                                worksheet.Row(rowIndex).OutlineLevel = count;
                                worksheet.Row(rowIndex).Collapsed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Saving the File
                package.Save();
            }
            // Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
```